# Extended view not working properly 

Tags: android, xml, android-view, android-inflate

I have extended a RelativeLayout with all its constructor.And I have created a layout in xml that I am inflating in one of constructor of my class.

My Code for MyClass

```
 public class MyClass extends RelativeLayout
 {
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        EditText edit_text;
        Button btn_clear;

     public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
     {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }
        public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_class_layout, this, true);
            edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clearable_edit);
            btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearable_button_clear);
            btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        }

        public MyClass(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    }
```

My class layout which I inflate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/clearable_edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearable_button_clear"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_clear" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And I use MyClass in my activity's layout like this

```
<com.and.MyClass
    android:id="@+id/my_class"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This works fine.
but when I inflate my class layout in constructor MyClass(Context context) then it doesn't work.

I am not getting what is the problem. I hope you got my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OK.
When we use a `View` in xml

```
public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

this constructor will be called.

Because all the attributes from XML are passed to this constructor using `AttributeSet`, so that these values will have effect on `View`'s layout and other fields.

However if you want to use your `View` in Java also, you should also inflate in all `View`'s constructor (*Which is recommended approach*).

Answer (score 2):

Please change your code like this

```
public class MyClass extends RelativeLayout
```

{
       LayoutInflater inflater = null;
       EditText edit_text;
       Button btn_clear;

```
public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   init();
}
   public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
       super(context, attrs);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       init();


   }

   public MyClass(Context context)
   {
       super(context);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       init();
   }
   public void init() {
       inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_class_layout, this, true);
       edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clearable_edit);
       btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearable_button_clear);
       btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
   }
```

}